Exoplayer - streaming stops after 8-15 minutes
I have an Android app where I stream audio content. When i put the app into background and turn off the screen, the streaming stops after 8-15m. I suspect device goes into sleep...I've tried aquiring wakelock, wifilock .. setting the exoplayer wakeMode, however nothing helped. Any suggestions welcome

check out battery optimization feature e.g. PowerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()
more info how to opt out in HERE
worth noting that some of manufacturers (China-based mostly) are introducing own battery optimization feature, which can't be disabled with above API calls, user must manually navigate to/find proper option in devices (modified) Settings. Few years ago I've met such "feature" on some Oppo unit
would be easier to guess what you are missing if you would post exact list of features/workrounds you are using (locks, ok, but smth else?) + some code for validation
